# Отобразить топ 10 записей в датасете pandas, которые требовали самого длительного времени исправления

Tags: python, pandas

Есть [датафрейм](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10plr5SRXT4iqMDoE1Lfev1R2bs-h_DIp/view?usp=sharing) Pandas. Нужно отсортировать записи по количеству времени потраченому на исправление бага (время на исправление считается вычетанием из поля resolved поля created). Я понял что сначала надо перевести поля с датой в другой формат, но выдаёт ошибку

(OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 11-11-23 18:06:00 present at position 23866).

Пробовал вот так

```
date_cols = ['updated', 'created', 'resolved']
df[date_cols] = df[date_cols].astype('datetime64')
```

Дата хранится в таком формате: 2016-04-11T16:35:57.000+0000
Нужно перевести её в приемлемый для pandas формат, что бы можно было выполнять различные операции с датами.

Comment: не стоит задавать один и тот же вопрос по несколько раз. вы бы уже начали изучать pandas, что-ли. там есть метод `to_datetime` - вот его и используйте для конвертации. либо сразу при открытии файла csv укажите в параметре `parse_dates` списком колонки, значения которых нужно перевести в даты.

Comment: @strawdog спасибо, а вопрос заново задал так как тот был неполным

Comment: @ЯрославСаух Лучше улучшать старые вопросы, чем задавать новые такие же. Таковы правила.